# Make link clickable behind another div

Tags: html, css

I have an html that looks like this

```css
.links {
  overflow: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.links section {
  width: max-content;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.links section a {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 500;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="links">
      <section>
        <a href="www.google.com">Click me and get redirected</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-layer"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ccastro95/61x5k4zt/14/

I would like to be able to click the a tag. It is imperative to keep **.links as absolute position**.

I tried using pointer-events:none but it didn't work. Also the **order of the elements is very important** and should be kept like it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click through div to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: Removing `pointer-events: none;` should make your link clickable

Comment: Could you describe the reason behind making the anchor element have pointer-events: none? Is there something else going on which we can't see?

Comment: just move the .links dom so its above the other content, i.e move it down after .text-layer part

Answer (score 0):

just remove `pointer-events: none;` from a tag !

```css
.links {
  overflow: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.links section {
  width: max-content;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.links section a {
  z-index: 500;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="links">
      <section>
        <a href="www.google.com">Click me and get redirected</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-layer"></div>
</div>
```